# How can I marquee the text content in Notification?

Tags: android, notifications

The text content is just too long to be displayed in the notification and it is cut. What can I do? Please help.

Comment: I dare say you will find a lot of information on that in the [Android documentation on Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView).

Comment: Thanks. It does have a lot  of information on the Notifications documentation. But, it does not mention how to marquee. I need to display the whole text content to the user.

Comment: Looks like the notification system is designed to handle custom layouts but not custom behavior. And quite frankly I think that's a good thing. Keeping notifications clean is more important than allowing fancy stuff. I can't see how you would introduce this kind of "logic" into a notification. Maybe you need to create a home screen widget to achieve that.

Comment: @Till - Regardless of the amount of information available in the Android documentation StackOverflow is intended to be a resource in it's own right. Even if the information is easy to find elsewhere there's no reason not to replicate that information here.

Comment: @SpencerRuport I was merely giving the OP a hint where he might find an answer, because sadly I don't have a satisfactory one for him. I agree that SO can be very helpful in finding your way through the immense information load the Android documentation provides. :)

Comment: @Brian1143 Could you please take a look, if any of the answers are helpful to you? I know it's Christmas, but I'd like to present someone with a few points. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

it Works for me, I have tested it.

First Create the Custom Notification :

as Shown here: [This Link of the developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

After that in TextView of message you want to marquee, put this line:

```
 android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

And It Works as you want.
Enjoy.
Hope it will help you.
Thanks.

Comment: Marquee is not very customizable aside from RepeatLimit: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:marqueeRepeatLimit No kind of speed control or say scrolling back and forth as opposed to looping: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6567

Comment: Sadly the OP did not say whether this is what he was looking for. But as far as I can tell...it is.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a Custom Layout for the Notification.  In the Layout, use a TextView for the Notification, then on the XML for the TextView, add in:

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
                    <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/place"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/line1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dip"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"                        
                    android:textColor="#00BFFF"
                    android:textSize="18dip" />
```

Delete any useless line and change the id according to ur code.