# How to make Notification text Marquee in android?

Tags: android, notifications, marquee

How can I make my notification text marquee from right to left?I am using a service to create the notification.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you have to do this using custom notification. [link1][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890882/how-can-i-marquee-the-text-content-in-notification

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

it Works for me, I have tested it.

First Create the Custom Notification :

as Shown here: [This Link of the developer site.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

After that in TextView of message you want to marquee, put this line:

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

And It Works as you want.

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890882/how-can-i-marquee-the-text-content-in-notification)

Comment: The original answer is present here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890882/how-can-i-marquee-the-text-content-in-notification

Comment: I am using this code for the notification creation. Where should I change the code. Please suggest me. notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.service_label_1), text, contentIntent1);notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;nm.notify(R.string.service_started, notification);

Comment: @Slasher_bd: Put this property on your notification text in xml

Comment: But whenever I am trying to implement it requires API level 16. But my apps API level (Min) is 11. I don't want to increase it. What to do next?

Comment: prefer posting a comment with the link, rather a answer If its already answered somewhere else and you don't have any modification to it.

Comment: Can I have an example or your codes for a easy understanding?@Ajit & @Lokesh?

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="Your-Text" />
```

**Edit**

```
public class TextViewMarquee extends Activity {
    private TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
        tv.setSelected(true); 
    }
}
```

Comment: if possible, can you provide me the notification creation codes as well? Which corresponds and interacts this xml laytou?

Comment: It is working fine to create a marquee text. Thanks @InnocentKiller. But still I don't get the notification text. Can you show me how to create a notification with this textview please?

Comment: i don't get you. What do you mean by `notification text`

Comment: The text that appears at notification bar, I want to marquee that text. Sorry for the confusions..:(